# How to filter by 3 or more criteria in azure dataflow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to filter rows using more than 3 conditions in Azure data flow, but I get an error in the expression.
How can I resolve this?
I would like to filter the company_code to those that are colored yellow.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the above and got the below results.

`company_code=='4901` in this there is no single quote in your filter condition. This might be the cause of the error.

This is input data.

[image]

I have used the below filter condition.

```
company_code=='7833'||company_code=='7828'||company_code=='4904'||company_code=='4901'||company_code=='7832'
```

**Filter transformation:**

[image]

**Desired Result:**

[image]

Comment: Ah... I didn't check enough.
I tried that and it worked. Thank you very much.